# why does \hline produce different thickness lines

Tags: tables

I am new to LaTeX and so still learning. I am using the following code and am surprised to get the middle horizontal line in bold. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Average Returns for Three Years Following the Stock's Listing}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{rrrccccc}
    \hline
          &       &       & First 6 months & Second 6 moths & First Year & Second Year & Third Year \\
    \hline
    IPO Firms &       &       & 144\% & 5.00\% & 152\% & 9.00\% & 5.00\% \\
    Size-matched Firms &       &       & 8\%   & 6.00\% & 17\%  & 16\%  & 7.00\% \\
    \textit{t}-statistics for difference &       &       & 2.03  & -0.41 & 1.8   & -1.09 & -0.21 \\
    Sample Size &       &       & 115   & 115   & 115   & 115   & 105 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}}
  \label{tab:returns}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: Hi ! Could you give us a compilable sample of code ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a viewer problem? Did you print the result?

Comment: most likely it is just your viewer snapping to an integer number of pixels, but  scaling tables `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{` doesn't help that effect (and leads to inconsistent font sizes with the rest of the document)